# Taylor series with a nonatomic variable

Tags: series-expansion

My series needs to be taylored *(groan)* in two ways. First, my function is actually a matrix, but that is trivial, since `Series` is threadable. But second, I want to expand in powers of `q-1/q` around `q=1`. Arguably, since at the limit `q-1/q~=2(q-1)` it suffices to include a power `2^n` handishly, but that's math (inner derivative), and also I'd prefer a more general answer: How do you emulate `Series[f[x],{y[x],x0,n}]` (which itself of course is illegal syntax), getting some `f=c0+y*c1+y^2*c2+...`, preferrably without resorting to `D[y,x,n]` by hand?

Comment: You may eliminate x from f and y (using Eliminate) and then expand the result in a series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `q-1/q` with a new variable, expand, and optionally back-substitute:

```
relation = u == q - 1/q;
q0 = 1;
eps = 2^-8;
ser = Series[
  Exp[q] /. 
   First@Normal@Solve[relation && q0 - eps < q < q0 + eps, q, Reals],
  {u, u /. First@Solve[relation /. q -> q0, u], 4}
  ]
```

[image]

```
ser /. u -> HoldForm[Evaluate@Apart[u /. First@Solve[relation, u]]]
```

[image]

Beware that `-1/q + q` is wrapped in `HoldForm`. To be manipulated in terms of `q`, you need to apply `ReleaseHold` to it.  Note you can't apply `ReleaseHold` to the `SeriesData[]` object you get after the substitution. An easier what to handle that is

```
Normal[ser] /. u -> Apart[u /. First@Solve[relation, u]]
```

It's better, imho, to leave the expression in terms of `u` while computing with the series, and convert to `q` for output purposes when needed.